# Type MyViewController does not conform to protocol 'STPPaymentContextDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm creating an extension on my class to conform to the protocol 'STPPaymentContextDelegate'. For some reason, the compiler complains, even though I have all the methods within the extension all declared properly like so.

```
extension PaymentPopupViewController: STPPaymentContextDelegate {

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    self.delegate?.paymentPopupViewController(controller: self, didFinishPerhapsWithError: error as NSError?)
}

func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
    if paymentContext.loading {
        self.indicatorView.startAnimating()
    } else {
        self.indicatorView.stopAnimating()
        if paymentContext.selectedPaymentMethod == nil {
            self.presentPaymentMehtodsViewController()
        }
    }
    self.indicatorView.isHidden = !paymentContext.loading
    self.paymentMethodLabel.isHidden = paymentContext.loading
    self.changePaymentMethodButton.isEnabled = !paymentContext.loading
    self.payButton.isEnabled = !paymentContext.loading && paymentContext.selectedPaymentMethod != nil
    self.paymentMethodLabel.text = paymentContext.selectedPaymentMethod?.label
}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: STPErrorBlock) {
    fatalError("Method isn't implemented because our backend makes a charge, not the app.")

}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
    if status == .userCancellation {
        return
    }
    self.delegate?.paymentPopupViewController(controller: self, didFinishPerhapsWithError: error as NSError?)
}
```

Here are the delegate methods as stated by the protocol:

```
@protocol STPPaymentContextDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)paymentContext:(STPPaymentContext *)paymentContext didFailToLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)paymentContextDidChange:(STPPaymentContext *)paymentContext;
- (void)paymentContext:(STPPaymentContext *)paymentContext
didCreatePaymentResult:(STPPaymentResult *)paymentResult
        completion:(STPErrorBlock)completion;
- (void)paymentContext:(STPPaymentContext *)paymentContext
didFinishWithStatus:(STPPaymentStatus)status
             error:(nullable NSError *)error;
```

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your implementations.

Replace this

```
func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error)
```

With

```
func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: NSError)
```

And replace this

```
func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?)
```

With

```
func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWithStatus status: STPPaymentStatus, error: NSError?)
```

Comment: I still get two "fix-it" errors wanting me to change from NSError back to Error

Comment: @FaisalSyed What about just changing `didFinishWith status` to `didFinishWithStatus status` without changing the Error to NSError?

Comment: I'll try that and let you know